# Accessing the execution environment of a function in R

Tags: r, function, environment, execution

I have a function that "prepares" stuff for the rest of the program. for example, the following function which defines two functions:

```
prepare = function() {
    f = function(x) x+1
    g = function(x) x+2
}
```

of course that once the functions executes the functions f and g are not available any more. They where defined in the execution environment of "prepare", which is gone once the function completes its execution.

My question is, is there any way to keep or to access that execution environment?

The scenario is that I get that "prepare" function from the outside, so can't edit its code, and I want to execute it and use whatever it does in the following manner:

```
my_function = function(prepare) {
    # the prepare function is supplied by the user
    prepare()  #this should define the f and g functions as above
    f(3)   # this wouldn't work normally, since f is defined inside prepare
}
```

is there a way to achieve that? that is, making "prepare" affect the calling environment, rather its execution environment?

EDIT:

found a workaround with use of body() which allows accessing the expressions inside a function, and build new expressions out of them, so I build a new function based on the "bodies" fo the "prepare" function and the "original" function. The real solution, as I thought through the problem was to use "aspect orientation". but unfortunately R is not aspect oriented language. maybe an idea for a new package :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the `prepare` function a bit:

```
prepare = function() {
    f = function(x) x+1
    g = function(x) x+2
    return(list(f,g))
}
```

you can access the functions like this:

```
prepare()[[1]](25)

# [1] 26
```

Or you can use `<<-`, which puts the function to global environment:

```
prepare = function() {
     f <<- function(x) x+1
     g <<- function(x) x+2
 }
```

Comment: unfortunately, I can't change the "prepare" function, which is supplied by someone else and passed as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
>prepare<-function() return(list(f=function(x) x+1, g=function(x) x+2))
> p<-prepare()
> p$f(1)
[1] 2
> p$g(1)
[1] 3
```

### Edit after a long  time

I had to come back to this for myself...

```
> prepare
function(x) { p = function(x) 5*x; q= function(x) x^2 }
> with( new.env ( eval( parse(text=deparse(body(prepare))) ) ) , { print(p(5)); print(q(2))} )
[1] 25
[1] 4
```

Comment: As I said - I can't edit the "prepare" function. it is written by someone else and is supplied as a parameter to my code. so your suggestion is not applicable.

Comment: How are you making sure that the someone else will have `f` and `g` in their function? In the same way you could ask them to either return a list or change the scope or.. write `f` and `g` in a separate file then you can call `myEnv<-new.env(); source(fileName, local=myEnv)` and access it through `myEnv$f`

Comment: see my edit. eventually I found a workaround using body(). In my scenario, it is up to the user to both provide the "prepare" function and the way to use it later in the code, but the code must be executed within the environment I create (and add more things to it which are beyond the control of the user).

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that `environment(fun)` returns the enclosing environment of a function --which defines how the function finds objects--, the following use of `environment()` allows you to access the functions defined inside `prepare()`:

```
prepare = function() {
  f = function(x) x+1
  g = function(x) x+2
}

my_function = function(preparefun) {
  # We call the prepare() function supplied by the user
  # that defines functions f() and g() and store its returned value
  # (WHICH IS A FUNCTION)
  fun_returned_by_prepare = preparefun()
  cat("Result of calling function f(3) defined in function prepare():", environment(fun_returned_by_prepare)$f(3), "\n")
  cat("Result of calling function g(3) defined in function prepare():", environment(fun_returned_by_prepare)$g(3), "\n")
}

my_function(prepare)
```

which yields:

```
Result of calling function f(3) defined in function prepare(): 4 
Result of calling function g(3) defined in function prepare(): 5
```

HOWEVER, this works ONLY because **the `prepare()` function returns a function** (in this case function `g()` which is *defined at the last line* of `prepare()` and therefore *returned*), implying that the call to `environment()` on the object returned by `prepare()` (`fun_returned_by_prepare`) retrieves the enclosing environment of function `g()` defined in `prepare()`, which happens to be the execution environment of `prepare()`!

If the returned value of `prepare()` were not a function, the above code no longer works.

On a side note, in case the following comes handy for some other application you may have: I wrote a package called [envnames](https://cran.r-project.org/package=envnames) that, among other things, allows you to retrieve the execution environment of a function by its name (`get_fun_env()`). In order for this to work however, the function has to be part of the calling stack at the place where `get_fun_env()` is called, which unfortunately is not the case in your above example.